# Finding the initial value that brings the system through two predefined values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have two differential equations:

$$\dot{\mathbf{x}} = f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \\
\dot{\mathbf{y}} = g(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$$

Given two states $\mathbf{x_{start}}$ and $\mathbf{x_{end}}$ which must be reached by the $\mathbf{x}$ function. How can I find an initial value for $\mathbf{y}$ that will bring the $\mathbf{x}$ through $\mathbf{x_{end}}$?

I'm primarily looking for a numeric solution as the equations are non-linear.

Comment: If someone would wonder the equations in my particular case are $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = (x_3, x_4, \frac{c y_3}{|\mathbf{y}|}, \frac{c y_4}{|\mathbf{y}|}), \dot{\mathbf{y}} = (0, 0, -y_1, -y_2)$

Comment: Please edit in additional information into the question text, that is what the "edit" button is for. Use the comments to react to comments.

Comment: Your equation for $y$ does not depend on $x$: you can solve it and plug the resulting $y$ into the other equation.

Comment: You are aware that in your equation, $y_1,y_2$ are constant and thus $y_3,y_4$ linear functions? Which renders the $x$ integration into a "normal" double integration of a function in $t$. -- Which does not change the non-linear nature of the overall problem.

Comment: @LutzL I deliberately didn't added my particular equations to the question because I want to know how these kinds of problems are solved in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a boundary value problem, it is solved by so called shooting methods, either single or multiple.

In short, you treat $y_{\rm start}$ as free variables and $x_{\rm end}$ as function values which gives you a $4×4$ non-linear system. This is then solved by you favorite non-linear solver, Newton, Broyden, genetic algorithms,...

By extending the ODE system for the first derivatives, it is possible to obtain the Jacobian of that function alongside the numerical solution, so that Newton is then easy to perform.

Note that as in any non-linear system, there may be multiple solutions, degenerate solutions or cases with no solution.